# Deploying my web application in IBM WebSphere Application Server Liberty 17.0.0.2 raising error

Tags: java, server, websphere, websphere-liberty

I deployed my web application in IBM WebSphere Application Server Liberty 17.0.0.2 and when I am trying to access it getting following error:

```
Error Message: javax.servlet.ServletException: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class 
com.x.y.z
Error Code: 500
Target Servlet: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor
Error Stack: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.x.y.z at
 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:1021) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1143) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4983) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.osgi.webapp.WebApp31.handleRequest(WebApp31.java:528) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:315) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1025) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:280) 
 at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:967) 
 at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:359) 
 at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:318) 
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:471) 
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:405) 
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:285) 
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:66) 
 at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504) 
 at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574) 
 at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929) 
 at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
```

Comment: I am using WebSphere Application Server Liberty very first time. Please give your valuable suggestion

Comment: What's com.x.y.z and how is it packaged?

Comment: @covener : Its a package in our internal application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the com.x.y.z is a 3rd party package, you'll need to set visibility of the third-party API packages in the Liberty server.xml to allow the application to access them.

Hopefully this documentation should help: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_classloader_3p_apis.html